# Test component using combineLatest

Tags: angular, rxjs, jestjs

Trying to unit test a component that has the `rxjs` `combineLatest` call to `Ngrx` selectors. I can't seem to find a way to mock the returned data.

I've tried using `jasmine-marbles` and `of()` neither seems to flush the data.

function

```js
private onSelectedCard(selectedCard: Card) {
    this.selectedCard = selectedCard;
    if (this.selectedCard !== undefined) {
      this.storeSelectLatest$ = combineLatest(
        this.store.pipe(select(fromBacklog.getListById(this.selectedCard.planId, this.selectedCard.listId))),
        this.store.pipe(select(fromBacklog.getPlanById(this.selectedCard.planId))),
        this.store.pipe(select(fromBacklog.getPlans)),
        (list, plan, plans) => ({ list, plan, plans }),
      );

      this.storeSelectLatest$.pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)).subscribe(({ list, plan, plans }) => {
        this.listWithSelectedCard = list;
        this.activeListsOnPlanWithSelectedCard = [...plan.lists.filter(listInPlan => listInPlan.id !== 0 && listInPlan.active)];
        this.plansLoaded = plans;
        const cardIndex: number = list.cards.findIndex(card => card.id === this.selectedCard.id);
        const listIndex: number = this.activeListsOnPlanWithSelectedCard.findIndex(l => l.id === list.id);
        const planIndex: number = plans.findIndex(p => p.id === plan.id);

        this.canMoveUp = cardIndex > 0 || planIndex > 0 || listIndex > 0;

        this.canMoveDown =
          (cardIndex >= 0 && cardIndex < list.cards.length - 1) ||
          planIndex < plans.length - 1 ||
          listIndex < this.activeListsOnPlanWithSelectedCard.length - 1;
      });
    }
  }
```

Test

```
it('should highlight all the buttons for a selected card in the middle of the list', async(() => {
      component.storeSelectLatest$ = cold('-a', { a: { list: mockList, board: mockBoard, boards: [mockBoard] } });

      component['onSelectedCard'](mockCard);

      getTestScheduler().flush();
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(component.canMoveUp).toBeTruthy();
    }));
```

also tried

```
it.only('should highlight all the buttons for a selected card in the middle of the list', async(() => {
      component.storeSelectLatest$ = of({ list: mockList, board: mockBoard, boards: [mockBoard] });

      component['onSelectedCard'](mockCard);

      expect(component.canMoveUp).toBeTruthy();
    }));
```

expect the test to pass. 
Instead, I'm getting

> TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected.
>   You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, ngrx 8 allows you to mock selectors:

https://medium.com/ngrx/announcing-ngrx-version-8-ngrx-data-create-functions-runtime-checks-and-mock-selectors-a44fac112627

If you don't want to upgrade, I'd recommend getting around this by mocking the calls to `store.pipe`, and having them return an observable of your choosing.That said, the upgrade is fairly trivial in terms of code changes and offers a ton of value.

Comment: Yes I could mock out the `store.pipe = jest.fn(() => mockList)` however the issue is this needs to be done for a combineLatest meaning there is more than one call of store

Comment: Why not just do multiple?

Comment: `store.pipe = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(of(false)).mockReturnValueOnce(of(true));`